# Make git log produce command output 'inline'

Tags: git, logging

I do not know how to better word this.

When I run any git log command, it produces an output in a 'window' of its own. I need to hit q to come back to the prompt and then all the log display is gone.

Is there any way to produce the log output 'inline' so the log output is displayed followed by the prompt?

Comment: You need to press q because the output uses a pager. If you don't want it, you could add `--no-pager` between git and its subcommand. `git --no-pager log` for example.

Comment: Also (assuming *nix), if you want to make `git log` simply print to `stdout` by default, you can set the `core.pager` config variable to use `cat` (instead of `less`, which is used per default). Ie. to set the config variable in your global gitconfig, run `git config --global core.pager cat`.

Comment: Also, if the pager is `less`, you can set LESS environment variable to include `-FX` (`--quit-if-one-screen --no-init`) options. The first option will spare you from hitting`q` key for short output (like `git log -1`), the second will make it "stick" in stdout after `less` exits (which is probably what you mean by displaying "inline").

Comment: @eush77 that would be the ideal behaviour, indeed. I am using zsh.  And have no idea about how to set environment variable. Will you please elaborate on that?
Also, will your please convert this comment into an answer? I will then accept it.
Lastly, I have added git cofig -- global core.pager "less --quit-if-one-screen --no-init" to solve the problem for git :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The reason the output of `git log` does not stay in the terminal history after `git` exits is that the pager program `git` uses to display its output emits [escape sequences](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288962/what-does-1049h-and-1h-ansi-escape-sequences-do) to switch to the alternate display buffer to keep the main buffer intact. This is usually a useful feature.

Some pagers allow to disable this buffer switching. For example, if the pager is `less` (the default one on Unix-like systems), you can set `LESS` environment variable in your shell config file:

```
export LESS="--no-init"
```

This will turn `-X, --no-init` option on by default (which can then be turned off by a `-+X` switch on the command line). The effect is that the output of `git log` will be written in the main buffer, and as a result stay in the terminal history.

If the pager supports buffer switching, but does not have a way to turn it off, then the only solution is not to use such a pager for `git log` output.

Switch the pager to something else:

```
$ git config --global core.pager less
```

Or disable paging for `git log`:

```
$ git config --global pager.log false
```

Or even completely — for every other `git` command:

```
$ git config --global core.pager cat
```

> When I run any `git log` command, it produces an output in a 'window' of its own. I need to hit <kbd>q</kbd> to come back to the prompt

As for this part of your question, I'd say that you don't actually *want* megabytes of `git log` output be spilled in your terminal every time you run `git log`. Features pagers provide you with are generally very useful: scrolling, searching, jumping, changing files, running commands and so on.

What you probably want is to bypass the pager for short output. `git` does not provide this functionality, but some pagers do. For example, if you're using `less`, you can add `-F, --quit-if-one-screen` option to `LESS` environment variable in your shell config:

```
export LESS="--no-init --quit-if-one-screen"
```

This will make `less` exit automatically if the entire output can be displayed in a single screen.

Answer (score 15):

use the following command:

```
git log | cat
```

The output of git log will be shown on terminal by cat.